# Can a website get hacked by copying a cookie and spoofing the IP?

Tags: authentication, ip, session-cookies

If someone can both copy the website cookies and show himself as having the same IP address, can he hack a website?

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on what kind of access the token stored in that cookie allows for. You can be sure the 'hacker' has access to the same resources as that of the compromised token (user). Which might be profile information, etc. Depending on what kind of website it is. You also often don't need the same ip adress only the token.